# Checking what functions you have defined in the REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Is there any nice REPL command which will return function definitions of everything you have defined?
Failing that something similar to `!:` in SBT which shows all previous commands.
Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to get to the defined functions with intp, but it's definitely not the same as the answer linked by @om-nom-nom